# Study the convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}x^{3n}$

Tags: real-analysis

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}x^{3n}$ , for $x \in (0,\infty)$

I found R =$\lim_{n\to\infty} \lvert\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\rvert= \frac{(n!)^2\cdot (2n)!\cdot2(n+1)}{(2n)!\cdot (n+1)!^2} = \frac{2(n+1)}{(n+1)^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{n+1}=0 $, so the convergence radius is (0,0)= $\emptyset$ and the convergence set= {0}.

So the series converges for $ x^3 = 0 $ , i.e. it converges for $ x = 0 $.

It means that for $x\in (-\infty,0) \bigcup (0,\infty) $  the series is divergent. I'm learning on my own and that $x^{3n}$ confused me a bit , also the 0 limit. Is this solution correct? Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually, the binomial coefficient $2n$  choose $n$ is about $4^n,$ with an additional factor of $\sqrt n$  that does not matter. How would you answer for $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^n}x^{3n} \; , \;$$   for $x \in (0,\infty) $

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is not correct since when you do the ratio test, you must include everything (not everything **but** $|x|^{3n}$). Namely, you have to call
$$
a_n=\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}x^{3n}.
$$
(and NOT $a_n=\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}$ as you did).

Then you have to study the limit
$$
L=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}\;.
$$
Clearly in this case $L$ depends on $x$; then your power series converges absolutely for all the values of $x$ for which $L<1$.

Namely:
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|
&=\left|\frac{(n+1)^2(n!)^2x^{3(n+1)}}{(n!)^2x^{3n}}\frac{(2n)!}{(2n+2)(2n+1)[(2n)!]}\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{(n+1)^2x^3}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}\right|\longrightarrow\frac{|x|^3}{4}\\
\end{align*}
Thus your series converges absolutely iff $|x|^3<4$, that is $|x|<4^{1/3}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your process is not wrong, but your calculation is wrong.

Given, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}(x^{3})^{n}$ , for $x \in (0,\infty)$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \lvert\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\rvert$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n!)^2\cdot (2n)!\cdot(2n+2)\cdot(2n+1)}{(2n)!\cdot ((n+1)!)^2} $$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2}$$
$$=4$$

Now, for convergence, $|x|^{3}\lt 4 \implies |x|\lt 4^{\frac{1}{3}} $

Radius of convergence $= 4^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Answer (score 0):

Stirling's approximation:

$$n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi} n^{n+1/2} e^{-n}$$

$$\frac{ (n!)^2 }{(2n)!} \approx \frac{n^{2n+1}e^{-2n}}{(2n)^{2n+1} e^{-2n}}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ (n!)^2 }{(2n)!}x^{3n} \approx \frac{1}{4} \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \left(\frac{x^3}{4}\right)^n$$

By inspection, the radius of convergence is $$R=4^{1/3}.$$

Or, by the root test $$\lim \sup |a_n|^{1/n} = \lim \sup \left[\frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{|x|^3}{4}\right)^n\right]^{1/n}=\frac{\left|x\right|^3}{4}$$

So, again, for $|x|<4^{1/3}$, the series converges.